# django collectstatic output no module error

Tags: django

I'm trying to run this command

```
sudo python manage.py collectstatic
```

This error appears:

```
Error: No module named cities
```

So I did a check:

```
prompt> python
Python 2.6....
>>>> import cities
>>>> cities
<module 'cities' from '/sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/src/django-cities/cities/__init__.pyc'>
```

Then it seems like I have the cities module there, but it gives me an error. Any pointers on how I can solve this? It works on my development machine (mac). I'm trying to deploy on my EC2 (running on ubuntu)

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Cheers,
Mickey

Comment: doubt this will help, but you _are_ running python two different ways... does your check work when you run `sudo python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the python interpreter specific to your virtualenv:

```
sudo /sites/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python manage.py collectstatic
```

This assumes you need to run the server with `sudo`.  A better way would be to run it under user space and proxy it via apache/mod_wsgi or nginx.

Comment: it works, but i tot having virtualenv solved that? i did a workon myproject. (myproject) prompt>> isn't it indicate that it is using the python in the virtualenv?

Comment: @Mickey: sudo doesn't execute in the same environment.  In virtualenv, try "sudo which python" vs. "which python".  As mentioned above, you should *really* consider running your django app in user space behind a proxy.

Comment: Okies :) Got it. I fixed it. Thanks a mil.

Comment: @JeffBauer how do you "run your django app in user space behind a proxy"?